# GWT-GXT FileUploadField

Tags: gxt

I tried making a form in GXT to upload files, but I see more examples on the net, I failed to make it work a simple FileUploadField to save the file locally.

Cde fragment:

```
    formPanel = new FormPanel();
    formPanel.setBodyBorder(false);
    formPanel.setHeaderVisible(false);
    formPanel.setAction(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "fileUpload");
    formPanel.setEncoding(Encoding.MULTIPART);
    formPanel.setMethod(Method.POST);
    formPanel.setButtonAlign(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);      
    formPanel.setHeaderVisible(true);

    fileUploadField = new FileUploadField();
    fileUploadField.setName("fileName");
    fileUploadField.setAllowBlank(false);
    fileUploadField.setFieldLabel("Archivo");                       
    fileUploadField.addListener(Events.OnChange, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {

        public void handleEvent(BaseEvent BaseEvent) {
            aSubmitButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
      });

        aSubmitButton = new Button("OK");
    aSubmitButton.setEnabled(false);
    aSubmitButton.setId("submit_button");       
    aSubmitButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent inButtonEvent) {
          formPanel.submit();
    }
      });
```

The above code is the declaration of FormPanel and FileUploadField.

Answer (score 0):

We use gwtupload-0.6.3-compat.jar library to do the job.

Basically, the idea is that on the server side you need to create a servlet, which is going to be accepting your uploaded files. The mentioned library provides UploadAction servlet extension facilitating that.

On the client side you can use one of gwtupload components. We use MultiUploader for instance. That's literally a few lines of code there. Main code is in the listener:

```
private IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler onFinishUploaderHandler = new IUploader.OnFinishUploaderHandler() {
    public void onFinish(IUploader uploader) {
        if (uploader.getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS) {
            // What you want to do when file is uploaded.
        }
    }
};
```

The rest is taken care of by the component. Since the library is for GWT, it comes with source code, so you can see what it's doing behind the scene and read extensive comments in the code.

Free to use of course.